# SSIS Child Package Name in OnError

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have taken the advice of many online and created a sequence container in SSIS to hold all my child packages so that it can also contain an OnError event to aggregate all the errors from all the child packages.

In the OnError event I have the following Expression task, with this expression:

```
@[User::AllFailureErrors] = @[User::AllFailureErrors] + "
Package: " + @[System::SourceName] +"
Description: "+ @[System::SourceDescription] +"
Error: "+ @[System::ErrorDescription]
```

It aggregates all the errors into one string variable which I then include in an email.  It's working great for the most part - it tells me what all the errors are, and the tasks (within the child packages) that errored.

However the one piece I can't figure out how to capture is the name of the child package that contained the task which initiated the error. It's hard to debug without this information, and I haven't figured out how to get it without renaming all the tasks in all my child packages with very verbose names.

Anyone know how to capture this?

Note that I currently have SQL Server 2008 R2 but will soon be upgrading to 2014 which I understand has some additional SSIS logging functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can does by using a Script Task in the OnError Event Handler in the child package to set the value of a variable in the parent package.  In the child package assign the `System::PackageName` system variable to a variable from the parent package.  It won't show up in the ReadWriteVariables field in the Script Task, but typing the name of the parent variable will allow the child package to access it.  The following line is an example using C# that assigns the name of the child package to a variable from the parent package.  Once assigned, the name of the child package will also be available in the OnError Event Handler in the parent package.

```
Dts.Variables["User::ParentPackageVar"].Value = Dts.Variables["System::PackageName"].Value;
```

Comment: I'll have to learn how to use some basic scripts first, but I intend to try this as soon as I can then I'll accept your answer if it works - thanks!